# Using Task vs Dispatcher for ui thread actions

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

I know the technique about UI thread updating from another thread.

So I have these two methods/techniques, which one should I use?

Using Task:

```
var uiTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  // change something on ui thread
  var action = theActionOnUiThread;
  if (action != null) {
    action();
  }
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Using Dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  new Action(() => {
    // change something on ui thread
    var action = theActionOnUiThread;
    if (action != null) {
      action();
    }
  }));
```

Comment: If this is a WPF app then there is no "better", pick the one you like.

Comment: Do you want to wait for the operation to complete? How do you want to handle exceptions?

Comment: @svick i don't want to wait for this operation and handle the exceptions at the 'action' action.

Comment: mh, i don't understand the downvotes...

Answer (score 2):

From a technical point of view I doubt there is a 'best' here. however I'd go with the dispatcher approach:

- it makes your intent more clear, namely that you want to get something done on the main ui thread
- you don't need to boter with all the task factory options
- Dispatcher makes it easier to hide everything behind an interface (1) allowing easy dependency injection and unit testing

(1) see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431421%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx) for example

Answer (score 1):

`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` does not guarantee returning you a `TaskScheduler` for the UI thread.

In fact it can sometimes return `null`, although these cases are rare and generally involve spinning up your own dispatcher in a native app (for example the WIX bootstrapper).

So I'd say it's safer to use the dispatcher version.